# How to vertically align the text inside a DIV without using display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

**My requirement:**

I'd like to create  a vertical left menu with SQUARE menu options with centered text like so
[image]

**What I've got so far:**

Text Not vertically aligned!

[image: Textt Not vertically aligned]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="LeftMenu">
    <div class="LeftMenuItem">Invoices</div>
    <div class="LeftMenuItem">Expenses</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    font-size:12px;
}
#LeftMenu {
    background-color: #0583c0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 8%;

}

.LeftMenuItem {
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#00619e;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    color:White;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;/* of course this doesnt work */
    padding-bottom:100%;

}
.LeftMenuItem:hover {
    background-color:#0095de;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7U53M/

**The Problem:**

The problem is that its not vertically aligning the text :(

**Other Solutions I've tried:**

http://jsfiddle.net/XpL5U/

I tried to use displays of table, table-row,table-cell. This did center-align the text but now makes the cells as long as the page.

**CONSTRAINT:**

I'd like to not have to use hard-coded pixels. I would like to use percentages.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* against setting height of the content with pixels?

Comment: @DanielLisik What would be the benefit to hard coding the height in pixels when there are dynamic options?

Comment: Updated my answer, now works on all kinds of content to be centered vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    font-size:12px;
}
#LeftMenu {
    background-color: #0583c0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 8%;
}
.LeftMenu_content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.LeftMenuItem {
    border-bottom:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#00619e;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    color:White;
    text-align:center;
}
.LeftMenuItem:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.LeftMenuItem:hover {
    background-color:#0095de;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="LeftMenu">
    <div class="LeftMenuItem">
        <div class="LeftMenu_content">Invoices</div>
    </div>
    <div class="LeftMenuItem">
        <div class="LeftMenu_content">Expense</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7U53M/7/)**

Comment: couple of things, the cells no longer look square-ish and I see uve used 100px as a hard-coded height..Im hoping to do this without the pixel count

Comment: @SajjanSarkar updated answer. Now just `%` as height and the cells should be square-ish.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can use line height, but that only works when you have 1 line of text. Here is a better solution:

```
.element {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
       -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
           transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

You can use whatever class name you would like for `.element` and then just add it to the appropriate items. You can read a full article on it here: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: I added this to LeftMenuItem in my fiddle and it didnt quite work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well when the parent element has more than one child element that needs to be vertically centered.  Otherwise, it's a pretty nice technique.

Comment: you need to add `-webkit-` prefix to transform to see it in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/XpL5U/2/. This is a great answer depending on your browser support requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the prefixes in my answer. I will edit it and add them now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on your design, the metrics are pretty much fixed, so why not giving a massive `padding-top` (something like 70%, or `65px`) to push the text exactly where you want it to be.
When it comes to the image, assign that as a background image to `.LeftMenuItem` with positioning `center 20%` and size `40px 40px`

http://jsfiddle.net/AFLdc/

Answer (score 0):

try to chnage css 
From

```
.LeftMenuItem {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00619E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

TO

```
.LeftMenuItem {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00619E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

may be it will correctly working

Answer (score 0):

The *square* requirement forces you to add an extra element.  Partial credit goes to Kyle Shevlin for the use of transform.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/rHbge

```
<div id="LeftMenu">
  <div class="LeftMenuItem">
    <div class="foo">Invoices</div>
  </div>
  <div class="LeftMenuItem">
      <div class="foo">Expenses
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#LeftMenu {
  background-color: #0583c0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 8%;
}

.LeftMenuItem {
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #00619e;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.LeftMenuItem:hover {
  background-color: #0095de;
}
.LeftMenuItem:before {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  content: '';
}

.foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```